# Remove white are from drop down

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this list:

```
export enum UserRoleType {
  masterAdmin = 'ROLE_MASTER_ADMIN'
  merchantAdmin = 'ROLE_MERCHANT_ADMIN'
  resellerAdmin = 'ROLE_RESELLER_ADMIN'
}

export const AdminRoleType2LabelMapping = {
  [UserRoleType.masterAdmin]: 'Master Admin'
};

export const MerchantRoleType2LabelMapping = {
  [UserRoleType.merchantAdmin]: 'Merchant Admin'
};

export const ResellerRoleType2LabelMapping = {
  [UserRoleType.resellerAdmin]: 'Reseller Admin'

};


public ResellerRoleType2LabelMapping = ResellerRoleType2LabelMapping;
  public roleTypes = Object.values(UserRoleType).filter(value => typeof value === 'string');
```

Dropdown:

```
<select class="custom-select" formControlName="role">
        <option [value]="roleType" *ngFor="let roleType of roleTypes">{{ ResellerRoleType2LabelMapping[roleType] }}</option>
        <div class="help-block form-text with-errors form-control-feedback" *ngIf="controlHasErrors('role')">
          {{controlValidateMessage('role')}}
        </div>
      </select>
```

I want to display different const based on the type of the page. But for some reason I get select menu with several blank rows and the desired list. Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: Note that AngularJS and Angular are two separate things. You generally shouldn't be using both tags unless you're asking about a comparison between them.

Answer (score 0):

To populate `roleTypes` array correctly use `Object.keys` instead of `Object.values`

```
public roleTypes = Object.keys(UserRoleType).filter(value => typeof value === 'string');
```

Next declare the `enum` in a variable in your `component`

```
userRoleType = UserRoleType;
```

Now you can get the values of enum in html dropdown with

```
<option *ngFor="let roleType of roleTypes" [value]="roleType">{{ userRoleType[roleType] }}</option>
```

A woking demo is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fnexnh).

Comment: hm... hid you skipped intentionally const ResellerRoleType2LabelMapping  into your example?

Comment: I tried but when I use `Object.keys` the drop down is empty - labels are blank

Comment: can you share a stackblitz demo?